# broken dependency: plugin org.apache.cordova.file-transfer depends on org.apache.cordova.file 1.0.1 but installed version is 1.1.0

Tags: cordova

I keep getting this warning when I try to add file-transfer to my project. Does this problem matter.  Will things still work?

WARNING, broken dependency: plugin org.apache.cordova.file-transfer depends on org.apache.cordova.file 1.0.1 but installed version is 1.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be fine.  Looks like there was a bug and it was not on the list of compatible builds

[Bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6844)